# Using React Redux Saga and typescript - my StateProps/PropsFromDispatch are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

### **What I'm trying to achieve and have done so far:**

I'm trying to fire off an action - the action LIST_ITEM fires properly, but I've added one more LIST_ITEM_BEFORE to fire in between the LIST_ITEM and LIST_ITEM_SUCCESS.

I'm probably doing/missing something stupid. In my react component it doesn't even seem to register the new value of "IsPendingList"  that I added.

I tried creating a whole new action as well, and got the same error.

> Cannot read property undefined of state.listItem

What I see when trying to access the listItem values are:

```
   {
"error":"",
"isLoading":false,
"message":"",
"isListItemSuccess":false
    }
```

Notice **its missing the "IsPendingList"** value even though I've added it in the reducer, interface, and the stateprops value in the interface for the react component....

....

I'm trying to add a value to the interface of an action I'm firing that looks like this:

```
export type ListItemAction =
  | { type: "LIST_ITEM"; data: ListItemData }
  | { type: "LIST_ITEM_SUCCESS"; message: string }
  | { type: "LIST_ITEM_FAILED"; error: string }
  | { type: "LIST_ITEM_BEFORE"; message: string };
```

I've added the LIST_ITEM_BEFORE to fire after LIST_ITEM but before SUCCESS.

I've created an interface, reducer, and action for this - it works with the first three items, LIST_ITEM, LIST_ITEM_SUCCESS, LIST_ITEM_FAILED, but not for the LIST_ITEM_BEFORE.

The reducer and interface is:

**Reducer:**

```
const listToken = function (
  state = initialStateListItem,
  action: ListItemAction
): ListItemState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIST_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        message: "",
        isLoading: true,
        isListItemSuccess: false,
        isPendingList: false,
      };
    case LIST_ITEM_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        message: action.message,
        isLoading: false,
        error: "",
        isListItemSuccess: true,
        isPendingList: false,
      };
    case LIST_ITEM_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        message: "",
        isLoading: false,
        error: action.error,
        isListItemSuccess: false,
        isPendingList: false,
      };
    case LIST_ITEM_BEFORE:
      return {
        ...state,
        message: action.message,
        isLoading: true,
        isListItemSuccess: false,
        isPendingList: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Interface:**

```
export interface ListItemState {
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: string;
  message: any;
  isListItemSuccess: boolean;
  isPendingList: boolean;
}

export const initialStateListItem: ListItemState = {
  error: "",
  isLoading: false,
  message: "",
  isListItemSuccess: false,
  isPendingList: false,
};
```

Finally in my react component this is how I'm using/calling it.

**Main react component:**

```
    const mapStateToProps = (state: stateProps) => ({
     
      listItem: state.listItem,       <------ DEFINED BUT MISSING "ISPENDINGLIST"
      listbefore: state.listItem.isPendingList,      <------- UNDEFINED
    });
    
    const mapDispatchToProps: PropsFromDispatch = {
       listItemData: listItemDataAction,
  listItemDataSuccess: listItemDataSuccessAction,
  listItemBefore: listItemDataAction,
    };
    
    const formConnected = reduxForm({
      form: "ListItemForm",
      validate,
      enableReinitialize: true,
    })(ListingItem);
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(formConnected);
```

**React component Interface.tsx:**

```
import {
  listItemData as listItemDataAction,
  listItemDataSuccess as listItemDataSuccessAction,
  listItemBefore as listItemDataBeforeAction

} from "../../../../Redux/actions/web3.actions";
export interface ListingItemState {
  showModal: boolean;
 
}

export interface stateProps {
  listItem: {
    message: any;
    error: string;
    isLoading: boolean;
    isListItemSuccess: boolean;
    isPendingList: boolean;
  };
}
export interface PropsFromDispatch {
  listItemData: typeof listItemDataAction;
  listItemDataSuccess: typeof listItemDataSuccessAction;
  listItemBefore: typeof listItemDataBeforeAction;
  
}
```

Comment: I  have this problem OFTEN - whenever i add or change actions - so I'm obviously missing some basic knowledge about adding redux saga actions in a typescript react app

Comment: The name of the item in State Props has to match the name of the reducer? I got the value once I changed the name to match the reducer